# Auto login after logoff

Tags: autologon

We have a win 10 multiseat deployment with multiple Active Directory users on 1 single PC.
What we want to achieve is everytime a user logoff, it would log back in into their respective account. The setup has multiple AD users, but all of them are pointing to 1 single profile folder.

Is there anyway to do this?
I can't even figure out how to do this locally.
The AutoAdminLogon regedit trick only works after reboot, not logoff.

thanks

Comment: "***we want to achieve is everytime a user logoff, it would log back in into their respective account***" . . . Then just tell the user to not logoff in the first place? Apparently in this AD environment, security is not an issue? What is this supposed to accomplish or what problem is this solving for you exactly? Why would you want a user account that is logged off and in AD to log back onto the machine automatically after someone explicitly logs off the machine?

Comment: The real login process is executed by our billing program. And the billing automatically logs off once a user is finished, therefore there would be multiple profiles selection after logoff and we need each user to auto-assigned to them.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "multiseat deployment" of Windows 10? Are you using 3rd party software for such a setup, is this a terminal server, or what?

Comment: I'm using aster multiseat + mandatory profile to ensure kiosk state on every login. The profiles are stored in separate server and each terminal are running multiple clients, www.ibik.ru for details